Ranking the best products based on availability
Let's say I have a typical sales dataset where I have a row per order number and the individual products in each order. With this dataset, I am asked to recommend a new product.
My initial approach would be to find the best selling products based on units sold. Then determine what the common attributes of most popular products are and design something new with those attributes.
Seems simple enough, but I'm struggling with how to even determine the "best selling" products. If I simply determine total sales per product and sort, I feel like I'm not accounting for the fact that some products were available in more stores or for a longer time period than others.
I'm wondering what's a better method/metric to use to take into account a product's "availability". Should I just normalize the number of units sold by dividing by # of retailers and/or days available?

Is associative rule mining what you are looking for? E.g., customers that bought milk and eggs usually bought butter. A customer bought milk and eggs, let's suggest some butter to them.

Maybe? Because I'm thinking of creating a new product from the study as opposed recommending an existing one if that makes sense. So a very stupid example is something like customers bought laptops and toasters, we should make a smart toaster.

Oh sorry. I thought your problem was different. Associative rule mining isn't what you are looking for. Optimization metrics are almost always domain dependent. I suggest doing a couple of test runs with the metrics you've come up with so far to see if you agree with the outputs and that the metric captures your intent. A lot of times "best selling" more or less means many units sold. To your point though if you sold a lot of units and something was only available in one store, it is probably a hotter item than something with similar volume aggregated across many stores.

I guess the problem of doing a couple of tests and see if it makes "sense" to me is that i might fall into trap of confirmation bias.

If you are worried about availibility, indeed then normalize by store-days (i.e. if item A was available in store 1 for 10 days, store 2 for 20 days, and store 3 for 30 days, the store-days would be 60). This is similar to using "passenger-miles" for traffic statistics to account for differences in numebr of passengers per vehicle and distances travelled. Now, you may also differentiate between the number of items sold, or the $ amount of items sold (a few expensive items, or many cheap ones). A better metric would be total profits (but do you have access to this?).

Yea using profits is a good idea.
